# Magento2 How can I choose multiple products by SKU?

Tags: magento2, sku, widget, product-chooser

How can I choose multiple products by SKU in a widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use the Conditions class that is used for the Catalog Product List widget. Code can be found in vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/etc/widget.xml but the main bit you need is:

```
<parameter name="condition" xsi:type="conditions" visible="true" required="true" sort_order="10"
           class="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\Widget\Conditions">
    <label translate="true">Conditions</label>
</parameter>
```

You could then choose something like I've done in the image below and would have the flexibility to filter by other attributes if you wanted to.

[image: Choose multiple SKUs]

Comment: I need somehow to get only the sku product chooser functionality, not all of the conditions :D